# Calling lists when lists when lists are empty in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wish to print from a list where the user enters an input and then has that input printed from a list. This however doesn't work without a blank string in the list as it says that the list is too short for the data to be shown in a label. I want for this to have the input printed immediately after pressing the continue button not after pressing the next button.

```
from tkinter import *

class Traveller:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.names = [""]
        self.E_phone = "f"
        self.E_name = "q"
        self.count = 0

        self.go = Frame(parent, width=500, height=450, bg="snow", pady=30, padx=10)
        self.go.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.go.grid_propagate(0)  # to reserve space required for frame

        self.dataView = Frame(parent, width=500, height=500, bg="snow", pady=30, padx=10)

        name = Label(self.go, text="Name:", bg="snow")
        name.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.E_name = Entry(self.go, width=40)
        self.E_name.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

        menuButton = Button(self.go, text="Continue", command=self.dataSave)
        menuButton.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=4)

        dataTitle = Label(self.dataView, text="Here is all of the inputted data:", bg="snow")
        dataTitle.grid(row=2, column=0)

        dataExit = Button(self.dataView, text="Return", command=self.returnT)
        dataExit.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)

        nextData = Button(self.dataView, text="Next", command=self.NData)
        nextData.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=5)

        prevData = Button(self.dataView, text="Previous", command=self.PData)
        prevData.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=5)

        self.everything = Label(self.dataView, text="The person" + self.names[self.count], bg = "snow")
        self.everything.grid(row=3, column = 0)

    def dataSave(self):

        self.names.append(self.E_name.get())
        self.go.grid_remove()
        self.dataView.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.dataView.grid_propagate(0)
        # clearing the entry boxes
        self.E_name.delete(0, END)

    def returnT(self):
        self.dataView.grid_remove()
        self.go.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.go.grid_propagate(0)

   def NData(self):
        self.count = self.count + 1
        self.everything.configure(text = "The person " + self.names[self.count])


def PData(self):
    if self.count >= 1:
        self.count = self.count - 1
        self.everything.configure(text = "The person " + self.names[self.count])



# main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Traveller Details")
    play = Traveller(root)
    root.geometry("500x450+0+0")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please show the _actual_ error.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking